# How can i pause or stop a video when i push another video onto the stack using expo video player?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

When I use this.props.navigation.push onto the navigation stack, my video continues to play in the background. Is there a way I can pause or stop the video as I navigate away?

```
<VideoPlayer
    videoProps={{
        shouldPlay: true,
        resizeMode: Video.RESIZE_MODE_CONTAIN,
        isMuted: false,
        source: {
            uri: this.props.navigation.state.params.video,
        },
    }}
    isPortrait
    playFromPositionMillis={0}
    showFullscreenButton
    switchToLandscape={() => 
        ScreenOrientation.allowAsync(ScreenOrientation.Orientation.LANDSCAPE)
    }
    switchToPortrait={() => 
        ScreenOrientation.allowAsync(ScreenOrientation.Orientation.PORTRAIT)
    }
/>
```

Let me know if any further details are needed to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `react-navigation` you can use listeners on the navigation lifecycle events. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle

There are four events you can subscribe to:

> - `willFocus` - the screen will focus
> - `didFocus` - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
> - `willBlur` - the screen will be unfocused
> - `didBlur` - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)

You can subscribe to as many of them as you want. Here is an example of using `willBlur`. You could easily replicate this for all that you require.

```
componentDidMount () {
  // add listener 
  this.willBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('willBlur', this.willBlurAction);
}

componentWillUmount () {
  // remove listener
  this.willBlurSubscription.remove();
}

willBlurAction = (payload) => {
  // do things here when the screen blurs
}
```

`VideoPlayer` [VideoPlayer docs](https://github.com/expo/videoplayer) does not expose the same `ref` functions that `Video` [Video docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/video/#the-following-methods-are-available-on-the) does, but you can get to them by using `. _playbackInstance`. So you could do something like this:

```
<VideoPlayer 
 ref={ref => {this.videoplayer = ref}}
 // other props
/>
```

Then you could do something like this in your `didBlurAction` function

```
didBlurAction = (payload) => {
  if (this.videoplayer) {
    this.videoplayer._playbackInstance.pauseAsync();
  }
}
```

I have created a snack demonstrating it working. In the snack you are able to toggle between using `Video` or `VideoPlayer`. The video pauses when you navigate to the next screen. There are also two buttons allowing you to `pause` or `play` the video. 
https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/video-example

Comment: thank you for your quick response. what is 'this.videoplayer', referencing? and whats the payload being passed into didBlurAction?

Comment: `this.videoplayer` is a reference to your VideoPlayer. You can see it in the code above being set.  The `payload` gets passed automatically in the function. You don’t have to capture it, or use it. You can read more about it at the link https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle

Comment: read through the docs, implemented but I am getting the following typeerror subs is not a function. (in 'subs(payloadWithType)', 'subs' is undefined, have you ren into this before?

Comment: I haven't come across that error before. However, I have updated my code as I noticed an error in it. I have also created a snack for you to try it out on. Hope that helps.