# I have a video player in my react application but when I change screen the audio still plays what can I do?

Tags: react-native

Here is my code I have changed the prop play-in background to false but still it is playing in the background what can I do to make audio stop when I change other page?

```
    <KSYVideo
      source={{
        uri: "rtmp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:bigbuckbunny_1500.mp4"
       }} // Can be a URL or a local file.
       ref={ref => {
         this.player = ref;
       }} // Store reference
       volume={1.0}
       muted={false}
       paused={this.state.paused} // Pauses playback entirely.
       resizeMode="cover" // Fill the whole screen at aspect ratio.*
       repeat={true} // Repeat forever.
       playInBackground={false}  
       background.
       progressUpdateInterval={250.0}
       style={{ height: 400 }}
        />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i pause or stop a video when i push another video onto the stack using expo video player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604727/how-can-i-pause-or-stop-a-video-when-i-push-another-video-onto-the-stack-using-e). Although this is for expo the principle will work in a full `react-native` app using `react-navigation`. It would also be fairly straight forward to adapt it for any navigation system.

Answer (score 1):

Before navigating to another page `setState Paused` value

Comment: My page is in tab bar of home screen can you please tell how can I do that in navigation?